# Parent style depends on child's dynamic value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [countUp](https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js), which counts up to a number. See [demo](http://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/). I have a set of Bootstrap [progress bars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress) that I'd like to animate the number shown and the width of the bar.

Markup:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;">
    <span class="js-countup" data-count="80"></span>%
  </div>
</div>
```

The numbers animate fine with:

```
$.each($('.js-countup'), function () {
  var count = $(this).data('count'),
    numAnim = new CountUp(this, 0, count);

  numAnim.start();
});
```

Now I need to animate the `style="width"` within `progress-bar`. How can I make the width dependant on the value in the `span.js-countup` so as the number increases the width of the parent also increases?

*Edit* The counted number is applied within the span like so `<span class="js-countup" data-count="80">0 to 80</span>%`

*Edit* A hacky solution would be to trigger a CSS3 transition on the bar width of equal duration as the countUp. Although that may work for my exact problem, it wouldn't answer the child/parent dependancy.

Comment: I don't think the plugin you have opted has an option to capture each step and update any element.

Comment: I don't think so either, I opened an issue/feature request on their Github page. But in the meanwhile I'm hoping there's a decent way of making a dependancy via just javascript/jQuery that isn't too memory exhaustive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into `MutationObserver`, `setInterval()`, etc. and nothing is super elegant or simple enough for what you're doing. If you aren't opposed to adding a jQuery plugin, give [jQuery-Watch](https://github.com/RickStrahl/jquery-watch) a try. It watches an element for changes to properties, attributes, HTML, etc.

The following will get you started, but you might want to refine it a smidge. It's a bit jumpy to start:

```
$(".js-countup").watch({
  properties: "prop_innerHTML",
  watchChildren: true,
  callback: function (data, i) {
    $('.progress-bar').css('width',data.vals[i] + '%');
  }
});
```

Removing the initial width on the progress bar helps, but you should set a `min-width` as per [Bootstrap's documentation for progress bar labels](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-label) so the percentage always has a background.

[Here's a fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/kejox3s5/), but it won't work in Chrome because I've linked directly to the raw files on GitHub (Firefox and Safari work fine).

**Edit:** I've [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kejox3s5/1/) with a `min-width` of `3em`, removed `%` symbol from the label and passed it into `CountUp()` as a suffix so you don't have a blank percentage visible on your progress bar. `CountUp()` now looks like this:

```
numAnim = new CountUp(this, 0, count, 0, 2.5, { suffix : '%' });
```

**Edit 2:** This question has become a bit of an addiction for me. Using your CSS animation approach, you can save yourself some markup by eliminating the countup element entirely and using the aria attributes on your progress bar. Then just set the width of the progress bar to match `aria-valuenow` when you start your counter.

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kejox3s5/8/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.progress-bar {
  min-width: 3em;
  -webkit-transition: width 2.5s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: width 2.5s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: width 2.5s ease-in-out;
          transition: width 2.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$.each($('.progress-bar'), function () {
  var count = $(this).attr('aria-valuenow'),
    numAnim = new CountUp(this, 0, count, 0, 2.5, { suffix : '%' });
  $(this).css('width', count + '%');
  numAnim.start();
});
```

**Edit 3:** countUp.js will throw errors if the values are null or 0. [Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kejox3s5/12/) with some basic error prevention and the addition of a duration data attribute for greater granularity.

Comment: jQuery-Watch is definitely the solution for the general question of creating a dependancy. However for an animation it seems to be too CPU heavy when the numbers change rapidly, so I feel like that plugin is best used for numbers that aren't changed ultra rapidly. To create a smooth animation I decided to use transitions with equal durations as the countUp function. http://jsfiddle.net/kejox3s5/3/

Comment: That's a good choice. I saw your edit about using transitions after I posted my answer and had a good *facepalm* about it. Such a logical approach. Thank you for accepting my answer regardless :)

Comment: I added a CSS animation solution. Hope I didn't overstep, just thought it might prove useful for anyone else coming across this question.

Comment: Just realized you already provided a link to your CSS approach. I'll leave mine here for passers-by, but I apologize for not seeing your's sooner. They're pretty much the same, with some minor syntax differences. Is there a reason you're using `toString()` on your count variable?

Comment: I had issues a while back with something like `count + '%'` where it would throw an error, ever since then I just avoid it with the `toString()` but if it's unneeded then i'll stop using it. I think it's convenient to add the css solution aslo, i was thinking about editing your post originally but this works too.

Comment: countup.js doesn't appear to be checking for null anyway so you'll get an error regardless of whether or not the integer has been cast. That's interesting to know though, I'll watch out for that in the future.